# Why do my forms not keep their size?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2008, windows-ce

I'm currently building a quite simple application which targets a Motorola MC9000 device (running Windows CE5). I'm quite new to the .NET platform and I have a small but very annoying issue. Whenever I close a form design view and then open it again, the form's size is reset to 640x480. Has any of you encountered such a problem before ?

Update : I might be on a lead. It seems that my problem could come from the FormFactor property.

Another update : Apparently I broke my Visual Studio install by trying to add a new FormFactor in some configuration file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure the WindowState property of the form is still set to "Normal".  Look in the form's Designer.cs file for the assignment to the ClientSize property, that's what sets the form size.  Beyond this, update your question with any properties for the form that you see shown in bold.

Answer (score 0):

Can you set `MinimumSize` and `MaximumSize` to the same values, thus giving you a fixed form size? I don't know anything about CE development I'm afraid...

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Unfortunately, forms in CE projects don't have MinimumSize and MaximumSize properties, only a single Size property.